# Atom-live-server not functioning

Tags: atom-editor, p5.js

Ask Question

0

I have just installed the atom editor along with the p5 manager package using The Coding Train’s videos. I am trying to use Atom-live-server to view my code. However, when I hit “Start Server”, it opens up a new tab, with the server name, and doesn’t show any of what my code is supposed to do. Activating Javascript console ju

00%20AM Screen Shot 2019-06-20 at 10.54.00 AM.jpg 2173×1134 241 KB st shows the following message: p5.sound.js:211 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio (anonymous) @ p5.sound.js:211 p5.sound.js:4247 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio Tone.Context @ p5.sound.js:4247 (index):53 Live reload enabled.

![40%20AM|466x313]

My sketch.js code is:

```
function setup() {
```

createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); 
}

```
function draw() {
```

background(255,255,255); 
console.log(“HELLO”); 
print(“HELLO”); }

My index.html code is:

robby1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>robby1</title>

    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

    <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        canvas {
            margin:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

To clarify, I am using chrome on a macOS mojave. I am unfamiliar with html, but know p5.js.